# Change doclib folder by Url parameter

Tags: document-library, parameter

I have a parameter based site set up that uses both CQWPs and Query string filters to create a project dashboard. The last thing I can't figure out is how to change the folder of the document library by using a parameter. [image]

The above is a picture of the document library, each folder is basically a project, per se, having its own parameter based page. What i would like to do is basically dive a level deeper into the document library when needed. So, if I am on the project dashboard and the parameter for the "Accounting" project is passed, how can I show only the documents or subfolders of accounting? Basically if I were to click on the accounting folder and view the contents, that is the view I would like. Any ideas?

Comment: I assuming you are taking the user to the document library. Just form the URL in a way that it directly opens up the Folder.

Comment: i cant find any documentation on it.

Comment: So you have a couple options, you can create a view specifically for each and then link directly to it, or dive directly into the url `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/eric/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fteams%2Feric%2FShared%20Documents%2FAccounting`

Comment: that is exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be rethinking your design. You do not want to use folders for segregating the different projects within the document library. What if there was reorg of the projects or they got merged tomorrow? You really should be using metadata.

Create a custom metadata column for your projects and add that to the document library. Then, you can filter and segregate the documents using this metadata.

You can take this one step further by doing it with custom Content Types.

Comment: Folders have their uses, they become increasingly useful now that you can set default metadata values on folders so users don't have to set it themselves, as well as being a securable object, allowing for storing more than the thresh hold limit, etc.

Comment: @EricAlexander Agree, that's why my recommendation!

Comment: The project managers we have enjoy folder structure as it is what they are used to, unfortunately we tried metadata and they couldn't quite do it right, folders make it simple-- for the user